# Header Error while using laravel Mail function

Tags: laravel

While using laravel Mail function , I am recieving the following error:

```
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected
```

Here is my stacktrace obtained from error logs:

```
[2015-03-04 23:52:31] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' 

with message 'Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected' in /var/www/pickup/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php:342
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'Header may not ...', '/var/www/pickup...', 342, Array)
#1 /var/www/pickup/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php(342): header('statusText: Exp...', false, 412)
#2 /var/www/pickup/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php(375): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->sendHeaders()
#3 /var/www/pickup/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(643): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->send()
#4 /var/www/pickup/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#5 {main} [] []
```

My Mail function is :

```
public function sendmail($user){
        Mail::queue('emails.verify', array('encryption'=>self::encrypt($user->email) , 'name'=>$user->first_name), function($message) use($user)
        {
            $message->to($user->email, $user->first_name)->subject('[Pickup] Please verify your email '.$user->email);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of the variables you're sending into the `to` method contains a newline character, and that the `to` method expects you sanitize those values yourself.

I'd start with a simple `trim` call

```
$message->to(trim($user->email), trim($user->first_name))->subject(
    '[Pickup] Please verify your email '.trim($user->email));
```

If that doesn't work it means one of those variables has a newline in the middle.  I'd try logging the values, and then sanitizing the variables based on what you found.  Also, if you just want to skip bad data, wrapping everything in a `try/catch` is another approach

```
try
{
    $message->to(trim($user->email), trim($user->first_name))->subject(
        '[Pickup] Please verify your email '.trim($user->email));
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    \Log::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The trim method has no effect. Still the same error. The place where I am calling the mail function is already in try catch block.